# Wordpress Network (multisite) -- how to ensure each site has their own admin URL?

Tags: multisite, rewrite-rules, nginx

I would like my multisite network install to be at something like:

```
https://mybusiness.com
```

Now my business has multiple clients. Each of them will be a "site" inside my singular WP install. So they may have websites like these:

```
https://example.com 
https://example222.com
```

Which means, I'd also like them to have WP admin areas like these:

```
https://example.com/wp/wp-admin/ 
https://example222.com/wp/wp-admin/
```

Is there an easy to accomplish this, with Nginx only? I do not use Apache, so some instructions that have been [suggested in other posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35364/url-rewriting-for-wordpress-network-multisite-subsite) are not entirely helpful. Also they do not change the domain of each site.

Comment: Are you asking how to get subdomain mapping working, or are you asking how to get Nginx to accept an incoming domain and pointing it to your WP multisite?  If the former, see the sticky post at this thread:      https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/  if the latter, best to ask at serverfault